# Выводить escape символы в file_get_contents

Tags: php, файлы, file-get-contents, escape

Есть файл, и его содержимое примерно такое:

```
text1
    text2
```

Если использовать функцию, `file_get_contents`, то она выведет как есть. Возможно ли получить содержимое страницы в таком формате, как описано ниже?

```
text1\n\rtext2
```

Answer (score 1):

> Возможно ли получить содержимое страницы в таком формате, как описано ниже?
>   `text1\n\rtext2`

Возможный вариант, того как это получить.

```
$file = file_get_contents('data.txt');
// replace \n with escape slash
echo str_replace("\n", "\\n\\r", $file);
```